# os catalina color profiles unable to find and delete. where can i locate them?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, macos-catalina

i am trying to delete unwanted col profiles that appear in photoshop print module. i have tried looking in profiles,col sync but cannot find them. example: Generic RGB profile.

Answer (score 0):

Get [EasyFind](https://www.devontechnologies.com/apps/freeware) (freeware) & search hidden files.

Be aware, some profiles are owned by the system so you shouldn't try to throw them out [it may even prevent you]. Others are exclusively Photoshop/Adobe, so should be OK to delete.